# Multi "/" in path after migration

Tags: wordpress, url

i have an issue after migration from joomla to wordpress website. All my images come to website and work fine but with inspector i see url `domainame.com/wp-content/uploads///////////images/products/p-14854-liver-250.jpg` can fix that some way? thanks

Comment: How did you do the migration?

Comment: do in request headers url of images like this: `domainame.com/wp-content/uploads///////////images/products/p-14854-liver-250.jpg` ?

Comment: i need to remove the "/" make path correct:      domainame.com/wp-content/uploads/images/products/p‌​-14854-liver-250.jpg